# incremental backup a single log file by rsync

Tags: centos, rsync, remote-backup

I use rsync for backup my jboss server log file. It is good for me.

but i found that when use rsync backup the log file, if log file change, all file will be transfer to backup server. the execute command like this:

```
rsync -avz --progress server.log.2015-08-30 root@10.0.172.30:/home/backup
```

I know rsync's  incremental backup is for file list. but how to make single file like log file use incremental backup. if the log file only add some line. only transfer the addition line.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I just had to use append tags.